# How to correctly implement multiple versions of multiple modules in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I have been trying to create a Google App Engine project that contains various modules, each with various versions; yet I cannot get it to work.

I went through everything on the [google modules guide website](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/) but their description of the hierarchy of the application is very vague. I downloaded a simple test application to see how it works (which I cannot get to work).

This is the structure of the application right now:
http://www.iteratorium.eu/stackoverflow/structure.jpg

and the whole thing is zipped up here:
http://www.iteratorium.eu/stackoverflow/flask_app.zip

There are three modules: default, my-module and mobile-frontend, and both the my-module and mobile-frontend have two versions in directories v_one and v_two. Each version has its own .yaml file, which contains a single handler (keeping it simple for testing purposes)

Is the structure at least correct? When I load the application through the dev_appserver.py file, everything is fine as long as I do not load two versions of the same module. In that case, this happens:

```
me@MY_COMPUTER:~/flask_app$ python ~/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py dispatch.yaml app.yaml mobile-frontend/v_one/mobile-frontend.yaml my-module/v_one/my-module.yaml my-module/v_two/my-module.yaml
```

Results in a traceback and the following:

```
google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.errors.InvalidAppConfigError: Duplicate module: my-module
```

(Both versions get uploaded onto appengine via appcfg.py without any errors, it might be only the localhost server cannot handle many versions)

If I only load one version of each module, everything works, but the modules cannot import anything from the lib directory.
Accessing `http://localhost:8082/mobiler` through the browser results in this in the terminal:

```
from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

I defined the path to the lib folder in the appengine_config.py file but it does not seem to work for the modules. That is where I stopped and decided to come here, since I am not even certain the structure is correct and I might be way off with all of this.

So... How far off am I?

Comment: As you said, the problem is that the local dev server can't handle to versions of the same module at the same time. That being said, it seems like the modules are NOT running appengine_config.py, so they don't get Flask loaded at all

Answer (score 1):

**note**: The dev server won't let you load different versions of the same module

You need the module definitions to be in the toplevel dir for appengine_config.py to get loaded.

Considering you really really want to keep the code for the two versions separated, a better app organization would be as follows (just showing mobile-frontend to keep it short):

```
root
  |__ mobile-frontend
  |   |__ v_one
  |       |__ __init__.py
  |      |__ mobiler.py
  |   |__ v_two
  |       |__ __init__.py
  |       |__ mobiler.py
  |__ appengine_config.py
  |__ dispatch.yaml
  |__ mobile_frontend_v_one.yaml
  |__ mobile_frontend_v_two.yaml
```

And having mobile_frontend_v_one.yaml being having something like:

```
handlers:
  - url: .*/mobiler
    script: mobile-frontend.v_one.mobiler.app
```

Comment: Still, I'd rather don't have different versions playing along in the same codebase, and would use git (as it seems you are already using it) to keep track of different versions

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're doing a little too much in the `appengine_config.py`, try reducing it to:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, 'lib')
```